# MVC form not submitting to correct action

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a simple partial with a form inside which is used as a search bar.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Projects", FormMethod.Get))
{
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="col-lg-3 pull-right">
        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Code" id="projectSearch" name="code" />
    </div>
</div>
}
```

This should post to my Projects Controller Details Action, however this isn't happening, and I believe this because of the [Route] attribute that is applied to the action, as when I comment this out, the form posts correctly. However I want to use the [Route] attribute.

The action looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{code}/Details")]
public ActionResult Details(string code)
{
    if (code == null)
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        ...
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

When the attribute is in use the form will post to this url:

> /Projects/Details?code=PP61

which doesn't map to the correct action. Instead I get a resource cannot be found error.

The expected/desired url should look like

> /Projects/PP61/Details

This works fine if I create a Url.Action or browse to the URL, so I know this action works, however it doesn't work with a form post. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one solution to the problem, it doesn't however answer why this wasn't working in the first place. I have created a separate action which is for the search bar to POST to, this action then redirects to the GET action which I was trying to reach in the first place.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult ProjectSearch(string code)
 {
     if (code != "")
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Details", new { code });
     }
     else
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
 }
```

This now works correctly, but I would still love to know why this didn't work to begin with if any body has any ideas. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Change [HttpGet] to [HttpPost] on the controller and FormMethod.Get to FormMethod.Post in the view.

Comment: "and I believe this because of the [Route] attribute that is applied to the action, as when I comment this out, the form posts correctly. However I want to use the [Route] attribute." -- As I said in the original post. I need the attribute unfortunately.